# AJAX html stubs -- is it practical to load clear out head elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I'm trying to implement a "as-simple-as-possible" solution for loading pages in the background.  I pretty much just want to replace certain elements within my html, with ones coming from the ajax stub.  I've of course run into the standard problems of:

1. JavaScript Dependencies
2. Styling Dependencies
3. Setting Title

My AJAX stub is fairly simple -- actually, it's the entire page, put into tags not named head or body (jQuery/browser doesn't like parsing these nodes).  For instance:

```
<html-stub>
    <head-stub>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="somescript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="somestylesheet">
    </head-stub>
    <article>Some Content to replace in the origin document</article>
</html-stub>
```

Is it safe/practical/completely stupid to do something like:

```
var stub = $(ajaxHTML);
var head = $(document).find('head');

// empty the current head -- later on we'll just empty things like title
head.empty();

// add all the crap
stub.find('stub-head').children().appendTo(head);
```

Or this is just a really bad idea?  I've tested in modern browsers and it seems to work ok, are there also pitfalls in older browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem with what you're doing. You could potentially do it simpler with JS or jquery templating. Also assuming you've taken into account SEO and accessibility with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic content is usually sent in a format like xml or json. Your stub is really xml. Then you set the innerhtml property of the desired node. It is pretty similar to what you are doing. Try giving your nodes id properties. Then you can access them more easily. You can say something like:

```
document.getElementsByTag('p')[4].innerhtml = some_variable;
```

or

```
document.getElementByID('dynamic_li').innerhtml = your_text;
```